# JAVA jar execution problem

Tags: java, ide, executable-jar

When i execute the application in jidea ide it executes fine.
But when i double click the jar file it shows the gui fine, then i click a button which must create some objects, but only some objects created, in that action call some constructors does not called. But when this is done in the ide all the constructors called!!!

what is the reason for this behavior? what would i do to solve this different behaviors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably missing some classes in the jar you've created. Check the classpath in your 
IDE project and compare with your system classpath. Any differences between those need to be included in your jar (or you jar-classpath).